# Flexbox Grid System w/Margin Gutters

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I would love to get thoughts on how to layout a flexbox grid system with margin gutters.

For example:

In my pen below I have a row with `display:flex` and I want it to wrap so I used `flex-wrap:wrap`. That all works fine, but when I set a width of 25% to all of the columns I have to set a max-width of a calc(25% - 25px).

https://codepen.io/Jesders88/pen/rwbVwP?editors=1100

What I would like is to be able to have a margin gutter and not have to use calc or max-widths if that is possible. I also don't want to use percentages so that I can have a set margin in px units above each column and to the left when there is a gutter value. So basically what I want is if I were to set a 25px gutter and the number of items on a row to 4 I want those to have 25px gutter in between them, but stretch the whole width of the row if that makes sense. Any questions just let me know and I would be happy to elaborate.

Comment: are you open to using `grid`? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/WOWQGP?editors=1100

Comment: I would prefer to use flexbox. Support seems to be much better.

Comment: If you're using a fixed margin for the columns, I think the only way to get the columns to fill the row is to use `flex-grow: 1` which won't work with a row that wraps, or to use calc() like you did. Are you open to having multiple rows?

Comment: If that is the only way to it, I suppose I will have to be :)

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't stretch the full width that it needs to.

Comment: k, I'll put together a couple of options

Comment: First off, this is a too broad question. Second, is this a school project where some properties is not allowed? ... if not, then you got it all wrong. Make no sense to not be able to use `calc` and percent, which is most likely 2 of the more important parts in a grid solution.

Comment: How is this too broad of a question? Honesty, I thought it was pretty specific. I asked about a specific part of a grid system that I was using flex for. The project is a personal project. The question was how to get away from using percent and calc if possible so that I could have the same margin above and to the side of the columns. I am trying to be pixel perfect here and have 25px on the top of all columns beside the first row and 25px to the left so that I can have equal distances between columns. I am not opposed to using calc. Just wanted to know if there was another way

Answer (score 4):

One quick and easy way might be to use an inner container and padding...

This would allow the 'gutters' to be formed by the padding inside of the columns, meaning each column can span the full 25% width that is desired. Then, the inner content container would end up being what you style to appear as the actual columns themselves.

So you would change all of your markup for the columns to this:

```
<div class="column">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

And your CSS to this:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column {
    flex-grow:1;
    flex-shrink:1;
    width:25%;
    padding-left:25px;
    padding-top:25px;
}
.content {
    background:#2848e6;
    height:200px;
}
```

Please note the addition of `box-sizing: border-box;` which will allow the padding to be a part of the 25% width, and not in addition to it.

For example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EXJVZy?editors=1100

Comment: It is always a shame to have to add more markup to solve a problem, but sometimes it really does make things easier! (There are undoubtedly more clever ways to do it with CSS alone - hopefully someone else will bring some of that to the table as well - I might have to think on it later when I have some more time and come back!)

Comment: I see one problem. If you look at the first container it is wider then the rest.

Comment: @jesders88 You are correct, that was due to the `padding-left: 0;` on the first column. I removed that (so that all columns have equal padding), and did it the same way you did for the top, and simply did `margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;` on the row. If you refresh that pen, you should see that they are all the same size now. Good catch!

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to use multiple rows and `flex-grow: 1` and don't use a right `margin` on the `:last-child`

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 background: #252525;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
}

.row {
 display: flex;
}

.column {
 flex: 1 0 0;
 margin-top: 25px;
 height: 200px;
 background: #2848e6;
}
.column:not(:last-child) {
 margin-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Or you can use `margin-right: 15px` on all but the `:nth-child(4)` and a `flex-basis` of `calc(25% - 11.25px)` (45px of margin / 4 boxes = 11.25) as the width.

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 background: #252525;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
}

.row {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column {
 flex: 0 1 calc(25% - 11.25px);
 margin-top: 25px;
 height: 200px;
 background: #2848e6;
}

.column:not(:nth-child(4n)) {
 margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
 </div>
</section>
```

You can do this very easily with `display: grid;` using `grid-column-gap` and `fr` units.

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 background: #252525;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
}

.row {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
 grid-column-gap: 25px;
 grid-row-gap: 25px;
}

.column {
 height: 200px;
 background: #2848e6;
}
```

```html
<section>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
 </div>
</section>
```